# Using if else inside Javascript filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

[image][My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7jmz/1/)

I have this fiddle. I want to use if else inside the filter function like this. The one I have works but the loop doesn't seem to break. Since it doesn't break, the else part is printed for all the not filtered conditions. How to break this loop? Or any better idea for this?

**I have two textboxes and a button, when I enter caption and qty and hit add, I want to check if it already exists on the table. If it exists I want to replace the qty to new value. If it doesn't exists I want to add new row with new caption and qty. The checking of existence is mystery for me doesn't work at all.**

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        debugger;
        UOMCaption = $('#UOMCaption').val();
        UOMQty = $('#UOMQuantity').val();

        $("#tbluom tr td:first-child").filter(function () {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(UOMCaption) > -1) {
                $(this).next("td").text("found it");
            }
            else {
                $('#tbluom >tbody').append('<tr><td>' + UOMCaption + '</td><td>' + UOMQty + '</td></tr>');
            }
        });
        $('#UOMCaption,#UOMQuantity').val("");
    });
```

Comment: So you want to break when you found the first element?

Comment: your fiddle does not match with the provided code, why?

Comment: if you want to return after finding the first element, add a return statement inside the if block.

Comment: Kind of a guess, but is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/GEwxw/

Comment: yes, if i find the first element i want to break the loop. and even if i dont find the loop i want to do the else part only once. currently the else part printed as many times as the number of rows that fail the filter condition.

Comment: @muneeb its a sample fiddle.

Comment: @McGarnagle your solution seems to work, but initially the table is empty and nothing happening at all, neither append is happening. i get nothing :(

Comment: Maybe I still miss something but if you want to only change the first one, you could use `.first()`: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7jmz/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the looping to break after first match then use

```
$("#tbluom tr td:first-child").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(UOMCaption) > -1) {
        $(this).next("td").text("found it");
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#tbluom >tbody').append('<tr><td>' + UOMCaption + '</td><td>' + UOMQty + '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Comment: return false not working on the else part,  if three rows already existing in the table then the new record is appended three times more..

Comment: @codebrain it should work when using `each` instead of `filter`.

Comment: this one nearly works but when i add the same UOMcaption if fails to check ..something wrong.